# New page rendering with a different font size

Tags: html, css

So here's all my code. I'm quite new to web design so I might have made a few mistakes. The problem is that when I load the `about me` page the font size for the navigation is smaller. I've tried looking for answers but none make sense to me. Can you help? I've posted this once but no one could solve it.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Home Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="main.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="logo.jpg" alt="Logo" width="" height="" />
            </div>

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li> <a href="index.html">Gallery</a> </li><!-- commenting out white space caused by display: inline-block 
                    --><li> <a href="about_me.html">About Me</a> </li><!--
                    --><li> <a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div id="socialIcons">
                <h4>Follow me:</h4>
                <a href="#"> <img src="facebook_Icon.jpg" alt="" width="" height="" /> </a>
            </div>
        </header>

        <hr />

        <div id="contentWrapper">
            <div id="itemList">
                <ul>
                    <li> <a href="#">Link One</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#">Link Two</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#">Link Three</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#">Link Four</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#">Link Five</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="itemImages">
                <img src="items.jpg" alt="" width="" height="" />
                <img src="items.jpg" alt="" width="" height="" />
                <img src="items.jpg" alt="" width="" height="" />
                <img src="items.jpg" alt="" width="" height="" />
                <img src="items.jpg" alt="" width="" height="" />
                <img src="items.jpg" alt="" width="" height="" />
                <img src="items.jpg" alt="" width="" height="" />
                <img src="items.jpg" alt="" width="" height="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>About Me</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="main.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="logo.jpg" alt="Logo" width="" height="" />
            </div>

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li> <a href="index.html">Gallery</a> </li><!-- commenting out white space caused by display: inline-block 
                    --><li> <a href="about_me.html">About Me</a> </li><!--
                    --><li> <a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div id="socialIcons">
                <h4>Follow me:</h4>
                <a href="#"> <img src="facebook_Icon.jpg" alt="" width="" height="" /> </a>
            </div>
        </header>

        <hr />
    </body>
</html>

*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

html{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body{
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

hr{
    width: 90%;
    margin: 2% auto; 
}

header{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    height: 14%;
    background-color: #ddd;
    position: relative;
}

#logo{
    height: 100%;
    display: inline;
}

#logo img{
    height: 100%;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    /*max-width: 359px;
    min-width: 288px;*/
}

nav{
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    /*background-color: green;*/
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
    bottom: 0px;
}

nav ul{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 28%;
    margin: 0 1%;
}

nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    /*background-color: #aaa;*/
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    color: #000;
}

nav ul li a:link{
    background-color: #aaa;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
    background-color: #ff5588;
}

nav ul li a:active{
    background-color: red;
}

#socialIcons{
    position: absolute;
    right: 5%;
    top: 15%;
    /*background-color: blue;*/
    width: 12%;
}

#socialIcons h4{
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

#socialIcons img{
    vertical-align: bottom; /*removing space below image caused by default vertical-align: baseline; property*/
}

#socialIcons a{
    background-color: pink;
    float: right;

}

#contentWrapper{
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#itemList {
    width: 18%;
    background-color: #ddd;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2%;
}

#itemList ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

#itemList ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: #000;
}

#itemImages {
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

#itemImages img{
    /*width: 30%;*/
    /*height: 8em;*/
    /*max-width: 180px;
    max-height: 180px;*/
    width: 20%;
    padding: 1em 2.5%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: I tested this with files on the same directory, there doesnt seem to be any problem. Is it just the font size that's the problem?

Comment: @Brian its the font and a image in the header which becomes smaller. This is a shortened version of my code that someone edited last time i posted this question. I will edit it and put the full code up as the problem may be somewhere else

Comment: I did not see any issues with font sizes either -- both pages are exactly the same.  

Make sure on each page that you hold `shift` and press the `RELOAD` tool button, (an arrow looping around in a circle) to make sure your viewing the latest copy of the web page

Comment: I still don't see any issues. Both pages work fine. Check the developer tools (F12 for chrome), see if anything shows up in the console. Also check the network tab and see if the stylesheet shows up red.

Comment: @MikeNickaloff ok so I copied all the code into a new folder without the place holder images that I've been using. Now the font is smaller but the same size on each page. Could the place holder images that i've been using affect the font size?

Comment: @ReeceBarrett it's important you understand the behaviour of em on font-sizes on nested elements. Here's an example i whipped up real quick to show how it can affect nested elements: https://jsbin.com/genohobupa/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @Brian thank you thats really helped a lot. From what I can see an em's size is relative to the parents font size. I have never seen rem used to size anything. I'm assuming that it is just like an em but ignores the parents font size.

Comment: Glad I could help. Simply put, rem uses the root element's font size as baseline which is usually 16px unless specified, compared to em which bases it off the parent element. You might want to look for a decent article about the difference and best practices. Hope this fixes the problem somehow.